# Finding the index of the smallest element in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to write up a block of code that takes an array of integers as an argument and returns the index of the smallest element in the array. Also, the function should return -1 if the list is an empty list.

[image: Test for the block of code.]

So far I have got,

```
public static int indexOfSmallest(int[] array){
    int index = 0;
    int min = array[index];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] <= min){
        min = array[i];
        index = i;
        }
    }
        return index;
}
```

But, I'm getting this error and unsure what I need to fix.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. You fail to handle the case of empty input array.

```
public static int indexOfSmallest(int[] array){

    // add this
    if (array.length == 0)
        return -1;

    int index = 0;
    int min = array[index];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] <= min){
        min = array[i];
        index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

If the smallest element appears multiple times, and you want to return the index of its first occurrence, change your condition to:

```
if (array[i] < min)
```

Comment: That helped a lot, but now I'm getting another error when I run this test. int[] numbers = new int[]{100, 4, 16, 15, 4};
System.out.print(indexOfSmallest(numbers));

Comment: @user430574 you have two indices that contain the smallest number. Are you required to return the first of them or the last of them. If the first, change `if (array[i] <= min)` to `if (array[i] < min)`

Comment: It was the first one. Removing the '=' sign solved it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd use an if/else condition to avoid having multiple return statements.

Comment: @NielsNet I like this approach TBH, as multiple `return`s also means less code needs to be executed which is better for memory and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `numbers` array is empty, and `index` is declared as 0, then `min = array[index]` will cause an error as you're trying to access the nonexistent first element of an empty list.

You should insert an `if`(before the `for` loop) that checks if the `numbers` array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException because you are trying to retrieve a value from an empty array in the line:

```
int min = array[index];
```

Just check if array is empty before this line using:

```
 if(array.length < 1) return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int indexOfSmallest(int[] arr) {
    int imin = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < arr[imin]) {
            imin = i;
        }
    }
    return imin;
}
```

or

```
int min = Arrays.stream(arr).min().orElseThrow();
int imin = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).indexOf(min);
```